# Denote that expression is differentiated, without differentiating it

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

I'm trying to indicate that I'm working with the derivative of an expression, without differentiating it. This is how it would be done, if I differentiate both sides now:
\begin{align}
y &= 5x^2\\
y' &= 10x
\end{align}
However, I want to differentiate the right side later, but keep working with the expression. How can I denote that I'm referring to the derivative? I suppose this won't work, but I would like to do something in this fashion:
$$
y = 5x^2\\
y'= (5x^2)'
$$
Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: Just $(5x^2)'=10x$.

Comment: So, could $(5^2)'$ be used to denote that the expression is derived?

Comment: I use this notation in french system and its valid however, you can use the dy/dx (in ur case d(5x^2)/dx

Comment: @Gustav Yes, of course. We always see it from the context.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write:
$$\frac{d}{dx} 5x^2$$
This is very clear.

Comment: Concise and uses notation that will be used throughout your career in math education.

Comment: This is the best way in my opinion. I'm not a huge fan of the prime notation most of the time.